# PHP referencing variables in an array as foreach keys

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I know my title is quite ambivalent but if you bear me, you'll find it is not so bad :P

I have a class method that gets quite different database fields in any order and builds an array based on those fields (each key adds another level into the array).

Now, that's the easy part. I also have a correction function that unifies the e.g. costs by some demographic data. The problem is that I need to address the right level in the correction formula.

I try to make an example:
I ask fields A,year,B,C,D and my correction formula for D depends on the year and C. I have formalized so that C and D are always the last ones to list but the problem is that how do I address the year so that I could get out an answer like `[A][year][B]=function(year,c,d)`. The fields are in an array `($retr['fields']=array("A","year","B","C")` (the result D comes automatically)

I tried to use foreach like

```
 $retr['fields']=array("A","year","B","C")
    $temp=get_data($retr);
    foreach($temp as $${$retr['fields'][0]} => $yd)
        foreach ($yd as $${$retr['fields'][1]} => $cd) {
            $output[$${$retr['fields'][0]}][$${$retr['fields'][1]}]=0;
            foreach ($cd as $a => $v)
                 $output[$${$retr['fields'][0]}][$${$retr['fields'][1]}]+=$v*$act[$year][$a]
```

and so on, but it seems that one can't use a variable variable as a key in foreach (or then I have got the syntax wrong). As now it just says that "Undefined variable: year"

Do you have any ideas how to express what I need?

Comment: `$output[$${$retr['fields'][0]}][$${$retr['fields'][1]}]+=$v*$act[$year][$a];` - No idea what you're trying to do there. Perhaps showing more code can help things clarify a bit?

Comment: I trie to make the code more readable. I try to return an array where the first level key is the value of field A, second level is year and the value is a function of year and the last two fields. It would be very easy if year would always be the second level, but as it isn't things get messy...

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved it, or rather not solved but programmed around.
For each foreach I checked the corresponding field and if it was year, I made a variable with value of current foreach key and referenced it with $$variable.

Like this:

```
$temp=get_data($retr);
foreach($temp as $varA => $yd) {
    if ($retr[0]=="year")
        $year_var=varA;
   .
   .
   .
       $output[$varA][$varB]+=$v*$act[$$year_var][$a]
```

I still would have preferred a cleaner solution but given my timeframe (or rather the loss of it) this should suffice.

I'm still interested in the "perfect solution"(TM)

Thx anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to understand your structure, but it appears you're fetching some data items and then categorize them into tree-like structure.

In this case, even though a particular attribute (e.g. year) appears on some upper level it's still, essentially, an attribute of the data item itself, so keep it as such: convert the "value" into a non-scalar (either object or hash). Then you would be able to work with those attributes without referencing outer loop values (and without resorting to variable variables):

```
foreach($arr as $subarr) {
    foreach ($subarr as $subsubarr) {
       // ... and so on
           foreach ($lastlevel as $value) {
               $adjusted = correctionFunc($value->data, $value->year, $value->somethingelse); // assuming value is an object
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have to dwell over it a bit. The problem is that the value is coming out from another lower-level call and I wonder if I can populate it. But I'll take a look on it later and this might be the solution I am looking for...